# Get class constructor by functional interface method signature

Tags: java, reflection, functional-interface

I know i can use constructor reference as hihger-order method's argument like this:

```java
collection.stream().map(MyClass::new);
```

But I have `MyClass` as a variable `Class<MyClass> clazz = MyClass.class`.
Can I use it to pass constructor reference to `.map(Function)` method?
I want to do something like this, is there a way to do it?

```java
Class<MyClass> clazz = MyClass.class;
collection.stream().map(clazz.getConstructor())
```

Comment: Depends on how hard you want to try. Easiest: `clazz.getConstructor(Param.class)::newInstance` - but that requires that the functional interface can throw some exceptions.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the point is to automatically infer the constructor signature.

Comment: Ehm, nope. Can't do.

Comment: When you have a `Class` instance, it may represent an abstract class or interface which you can’t instantiate, it may represent an `enum` type that doesn’t allow creating more instance or a type having no matching constructor or the constructor is not accessible. None of these can be checked at compile time. On the other hand, the inferred generic signature needed to select the right constructor is not available at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

***Standard disclaimer:** Use of reflection is almost always a bad idea.*

It is much better to go for a standard *Abstract Factory* or similar.

However, `MethodHandle` will construct the required `Function` objct with minimal overhead (I think). If you do the lookup of `fn` every time, there is overhead in that.

```
    Function<T, R> fn = (Function<T, R>)
        MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(
            Function.class,
            MethodHandles.lookup().findConstructor(clazz,
               MethodType.methodType(Void.TYPE, tClass)
           )
        );
```

Exception handling elided.